# Unity 2D player colliding with walls causes jittery movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Trying to make a top down shooter in Unity. Used the 2D (URP) core. Whenever the player collides with the walls in certain ways (sliding off the sides or colliding with the wall's corner), the player will begin to jitter and slowly move without input. It also moves towards the direction of the mouse. How do I fix this?

**Player script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float movespeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private float rotspeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private Camera cam;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator animator;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveInput;



    private void Awake()
    { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        SetPlayerVel();
        RotateInDirectionofCursor();
    }

    private void SetPlayerVel()
    {
        rb.velocity = moveInput * movespeed * Time.deltaTime;


    }

    private void RotateInDirectionofCursor()
    {
       Vector2 mouseWorldPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        transform.up = (mouseWorldPos - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y)) * -1;

    }

    private void OnMove(InputValue inputValue)
    {
        moveInput = inputValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
```

**Further components:**

**Player:**

- Rigidbody2D: Body Type (Dynamic)
  Collision Detection (Continuous)
  Interpolate (Interpolate)
- Box Collider 2D
- Player Input

**Wall:** (This is under a tilemap grid)

- Tilemap Collider 2D
- Rigidbody2D: Body Type (Static)

I tried changing the way the player moves to rb.MovePosition and the way the player collides with the wall into a script. Neither worked, although I'm not proficient Unity, so I might not understand what the problem is.

Comment: A few red flags here. `transform.up = ...` - It's generally not advisable to modify an object's transform directly if it has a rigidbody, you should use rigidbody methods to do so. `rb.velocity = moveInput * movespeed * Time.deltaTime;` - You're calling this in FixedUpdate but using Time.deltaTime instead of Time.fixedDeltaTime. You shouldn't even need deltaTime here at all since you're directly modifying its' velocity, not translating it across multiple frames. Using velocity to control motion is already frame-rate independent.

Answer (score 0):

This type of jittering and slow movement without input can occur when the player's physics collide with the walls in a way that causes the player to get stuck or trapped. Here are a few suggestions to try and resolve this issue:

- You can try adjusting the physics material of the player's collider to reduce the friction between the player and the walls. This can be done by changing the friction and bounciness properties of the physics material.
- Increasing the mass of the player can make it less likely to get stuck or trapped when colliding with walls. This can be done by adjusting the player's Rigidbody component's mass property.
- Make sure that the player's collider is the right shape and size for your game, usually capsule colliders are best for player controllers. If the collider is too big or too small, it can cause the player to get stuck or jitter when colliding with walls.

Hopefully, one or more of these suggestions will help you resolve the issue.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful hint.  On the walls, I had the same problem.  I was using a 2D tilemap, however.  I added the Platform Effector 2D Component to my blocks and walls.  It fixed my problems.  Make sure that when you add the platform effector, you select the "Used by Effector" checkbox in whatever collider is in effect (e.g. BoxCollider2D or PolygonCollider2D).
I'm not sure if it will help, but it is worth a try.